# Spire.Designer - Form Designer stopped working on Framework 4.5

Tags: windows

I have a project which allows us to create dashboards at runtime, this dashboard can have multiple control like gauges, bar-charts from DevExpress like [these](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Chart/).

I Have been using Spire.designer(from e-iceblue) as form designer(or canvas) in my application. I used to drag/drop controls on my form designer at runtime and it works great on framework 4.0, However now on Framework 4.5, i am not able to drag/drop any control. It shows me "Not Allowed" circular icon while dropping control on the designer.

Is there any other third party Form designer available, please recommend.

PS: The vendor of Spire.Designer, "E-IceBlue" no more provide support for Spire.Designer.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially point out your requirements as exact as possible; not everybody might know Spire.

Comment: Thank you, Bravo. Better already. As it's not my area of expertise, I won't complain further (as I cannot tell whether the information provided is sufficient to give good recommendations; I'm personally missing a list of requirements). Just to be on the safe side, let me point to the link of my previous comment again to cross-check. The more precise and detailed your question, the better your chances for good answers fitting your needs ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution to this problem. I removed Spire Designer from my project and Added "Greatis Form Designer" which supports .Net Framework 4.5.

This product is by Greatis Software. They are not providing any support, however I think it's fine as the demo projects and user guide are sufficient.